# Get All possible combinations of objects, where sum of values matches number

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

Looking to do this in typescript.

I have an array of objects, where each object has a property called `rating`. The array looks like so:

```
var objects = [{"name":"foo","rating":4}, {"name":"bar","rating":5}, {"name":"foobar","rating":2}]
```

Now I have a target rating, `destinationRating`, this for example: `var destinationRating=11`. From these objects, I need to get an array of, say 20 `key1;key2;key3` shaped strings, where `key1`and so on, are the keys from the objects array, where the sum of all the objects selected is at least `destinationRating`.  3 selected objects minimum. I have no idea on how I should apporach the creation of such an algorithm.

The end result should look like this, `[0:"0;1;2"]`, in the case that the first 3 objects of the `objects` array match the criteria.

Comment: please add some more data and some example, how the source look like and the wanted result should look like.

Comment: What is it you're actually after? You may need to re-evaluate what your actual goal is and take a different approach. With the problem as stated, once you get at least one combination of objects that match the requirements, the number of combinations is going to grow exponentially with the length of the array.

Comment: Updated OP a bit. Might not even have to be 20 combinations.

Comment: So instead of finding all possible combinations, you're given a set of combinations, and you have to determine which, among that set, match the rating criteria?

Comment: It sounds like you could probably accomplish it by iterating over the array of key strings, splitting each key string into an array containing the indexes ('keys'), and then using the indexes to sum the ratings (either by iterating in a loop or using a reduce function). Since you're learning, I'm intentionally trying to point you in the right direction rather than handing you an answer. Do some research on the concepts I listed, attempt a solution, and then if you have trouble post your attempted solution along with how it differed from expected results. Good luck!

Comment: Also, if you come up with the solution on your own, make sure you post that as an answer so others can learn from it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a proposal which generates all combinations of the indices (as long as they are necessary, see output) and checks the given conditions and returns the wanted result.

The result set contains strings with the indices of the given array which match the wanted sum of the named property.

```js
function combination(array, property, sum) {
    function c(part, i) {
        var result = [], p, s;
        while (i < n) {
            p = part.slice(0);
            p.push(i++);
            document.write(p + '<br>');
            s = p.reduce(function (r, a) { return r + array[a][property]; }, 0);
            if (s < sum) {
                result = result.concat(c(p, i));
            }
            if (p.length >= 3 && s === sum) {
                result.push(p.join(';'));
                break;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    var n = array.length;
    return c([], 0);
}

var objects = [{ "name": "id0", "rating": 4 }, { "name": "id1", "rating": 5 }, { "name": "id2", "rating": 2 }, { "name": "id3", "rating": 6 }, { "name": "id4", "rating": 8 }, { "name": "id5", "rating": 3 }, { "name": "id6", "rating": 1 }];

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(combination(objects, 'rating', 11), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Weirdly enough, for a dataset that's heavily big enough to combine from, combinations for sum 6 and under turn up empty... Do you cap at exactly the sum? Can go over that aswell, just that 3 elements is max...

Comment: you need only 3 elements? change `if (p.length >= 3 && s === sum)` to `if (p.length === 3 && s === sum)` or skip the length check.

Comment: I'm now implementing this for final use and I'm seeing some things that I could use a bit of advice on. When `sum` is too small to be made up with 3 elements, it ends up not giving me any combnations. In this case, i'd like it to provide atleast a few combinations that overshoot `sum`. How to edit this to achieve that? Limit is still 3 elements. If this can't be done, then I can work around, though.

Comment: i cannot give you some advice, because it depends on the special implementation. but don't hesitate to ask, if you have some more concrete problem.